# SignOut Social Media Auth - WebAuthenticator Xamarin Essentials

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In the mobile controller I am using await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); to get out of the session, but the section is left open

Comment: Wrap code in a using statement so it gets disposed when you exit.